# How I can get the contents of a text box in android auntomatica way? without user intervention

Tags: android, string, automatic-updates

I am developing an app in android and would like to develop a method that captures the text you type into the box, but do not want the user to press any button, but at the moment when the text is written on the box , take a few seconds and the text is obtained and then compare it with other text.

Comment: have you at least googled?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EditText.addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) method to listen to EditText text changes.

You can check this [sample implementations](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.text.TextWatcher):

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String text = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been a great contribution, must I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an onTextChangedListener to your EditText, it will look something like this:

```
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = txtMessage.getText().toString();
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TextWatcher` to you `EditText` and create an asynchronous task and send it to sleep the desired amount of time and then make any operation with the input text from the `EditText`. If anything changed in the text while the task is still running, then cancel the task and start a new one, like this:

```
private UpdateFilterTask currentFilterTask = null;

private class UpdateFilterTask extends AsyncTask {

    private String mInputText;

    public UpdateFilterTask(String inputText){
        this.mInputText = inputText;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            // Set the desired amount of time to wait in here, right now is 5 secs
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        if(this.isCancelled()){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        Boolean didFinish = (Boolean) o;
        if(didFinish){
            // Do whatever you like with the mInputText
        }
    }
}

private class SearchTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(currentFilterTask != null){
            // If there was a running task previously, interrupt it
            currentFilterTask.cancel(true);
            currentFilterTask = null;
        }

        if(s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            // Return to the original state as the EditText is empty now
            return;
        }

        currentFilterTask = new UpdateFilterTask(s.toString());
        currentFilterTask.execute();
    }
}
```